# How can I know if a token that I created is used in a smart contract?

Tags: contract-design, tokens

I plan on creating some tokens and want to create code that will execute if the one of the tokens is used within a smart contract. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you explain more about "if one of the tokens is used"? Used how? That will help me best answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can compare `msg.sender` and `tx.origin`; if the two are different, your code is being called by another contract. That other contract could be someone's wallet, however - or just about anything else - and it's probably a bad idea to make decisions on that basis.